React Native Error: Cannot read property 'openDrawer' of undefined
I am implementing a react native project in which I have to add bottomtab navigation as well as right and left side drawer navigation all the screens.
I have successfully implemented the tab navigation but I am getting errors while trying to implement the drawer navigation for both the drawers.
Every time I click on the buttons for opening the drawers, I get an error saying
cannot read property opendrawer of undefined .
Here is the reference to my code
App.js
import React from 'react';
import SignInScreen from './components/Screens/SignInScreen';
import SignUpScreen from './components/Screens/SignUpScreen';
import Welcome from './components/Screens/Welcome';
import Dashboard from './components/Screens/Dashboard';
import DetailsScreen from "./components/Screens/DetailsScreen";

import NiftyEnergyDetails from "./components/Screens/NiftyEnergyDetails"
import BankTrDetails from './components/Screens/BankTrDetails';


import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import Summary from './components/Screens/Summary';




import {
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';


function App() {
  
  
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Welcome' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} >

      {/* <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Welcome'> */}
      {/* <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Dashboard' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}> */}

        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} options={{ title:"Pavan" }} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />



        <Stack.Screen name="Niftyenergydetails" component={NiftyEnergyDetails} />



        <Stack.Screen name="Banktrdetails" component={BankTrDetails} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Summary" component={Summary} />





      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  );
}

export default App;

Dashboard.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import SignUpScreen from './SignUpScreen';
import SignInScreen from './SignInScreen';
import Watchlist from './Watchlist';
import AlgoTrader from './AlgoTrader';
import Portfolio from './Portfolio';
import Insights from './Insights';
import Home from './Home';
import Welcome from './Welcome';
import Hamburger from "../Assets/Hamburger";
import ProfilePhoto from "../Assets/ProfilePhoto";
import HomeActive from '../Assets/HomeActive';
import HomeInactive from '../Assets/HomeInactive';
import WatchlistActive from '../Assets/WatchlistActive';
import WatchlistInactive from '../Assets/WatchlistInactive';
import AlgoTraderActive from '../Assets/AlgoTraderActive';
import AlgoTraderInactive from '../Assets/AlgoTraderInactive';
import PortfolioActive from '../Assets/PortfolioActive';
import PortfolioInactive from '../Assets/PortfolioInactive';
import InsightsActive from '../Assets/InsightsActive';
import InsightsInactive from '../Assets/InsightsInactive';
import Icon from 'react-native-ionicons';

const insightsData = "NIFTY";
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const LeftDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const RightDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const CustomDrawerContent = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Left drawer</Text>
  </View>
);

const CustomRightDrawerContent = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Right Drawer</Text>
  </View>
);

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.getParent('RightDrawer').openDrawer() }}>
          <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const RightScreenDisplay = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Right Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const TabNavigator = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const openLeftDrawer = () => {
    navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
  };

  const openRightDrawer = () => {
    navigation.getParent('RightDrawer').dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
  };

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "Home",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: "600" },
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openLeftDrawer}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openRightDrawer}>
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Home</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            focused ? <HomeActive width={25} height={25} /> : <HomeInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Watchlist"
        component={Watchlist}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "FTSM Watchlist",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: "600" },
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openLeftDrawer}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openRightDrawer}>
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Watchlist</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            focused ? <WatchlistActive width={25} height={25} /> : <WatchlistInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Algo Trader"
        component={AlgoTrader}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "Algo Traders",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: "600" },
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openLeftDrawer}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openRightDrawer}>
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Algo Trader</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            focused ? <AlgoTraderActive width={25} height={25} /> : <AlgoTraderInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Portfolio"
        component={Portfolio}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "My Portfolio",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: "600" },
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openLeftDrawer}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openRightDrawer}>
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Portfolio</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            focused ? <PortfolioActive width={25} height={25} /> : <PortfolioInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Insights"
        component={Insights}
        initialParams={{ data: insightsData }}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "Insights",
          headerTintColor: "#0B588D",
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: "600" },
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openLeftDrawer}>
              <Hamburger height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 10 }} onPress={openRightDrawer}>
              <ProfilePhoto height="30" width="30" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => (
            <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: focused ? 'underline' : 'none', color: focused ? '#0B588D' : 'gray' }}>Insights</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            focused ? <InsightsActive width={25} height={25} /> : <InsightsInactive width={25} height={25} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const LeftScreenDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <LeftDrawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent}
      screenOptions={{
        drawerPosition: "left",
        drawerLabelStyle: {
          textAlign: "center",
          color: "blue"
        }
      }}>
      <LeftDrawer.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </LeftDrawer.Navigator>
  );
};


const RightScreenDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <RightDrawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={CustomRightDrawerContent}
      screenOptions={{ drawerPosition: "right" }}
      id="RightDrawer"
      // drawerContent={(props)=><RightScreenDisplay {...props} />}
    >
      <RightDrawer.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="LeftDrawer" component={LeftScreenDrawer} />
    </RightDrawer.Navigator>
  );
};


const Dashboard = () => {
  return (

      <RightScreenDrawer />




  );
};

export default Dashboard;

Home.js
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home

List of dependencies installed
    "@eliav2/react-native-collapsible-view": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.17",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.15",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-accordion-list-view": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1305.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-dashed-line": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.31.1",
    "react-native-search-bar": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-shadow-2": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-navigator": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0"

Can someone please help me out in fixing this error. Any feedback would be appreciated.

I am getting this same error but with the toggleDrawer function. Tried the openDrawer function too and I am getting the same error.
